# updating sql record to two tables

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

Respected Member

**my first table company has following fields**

- com_id
- p_id
- p_name

**my second table users has following fields**

- p_id
- p_name
- role_def
- com_id

**Question**

I want to update multiple record on both tables with below query as example.

Please guide as it is not being working

```
UPDATE company,
       users
SET company.p_name='Javeria Rauf',
    users.p_name='Javeria Rauf',
    users.role_def='Admin'
WHERE company.p_id=9
  OR users.p_id=9
```

Comment: You can't update two tables at once in one statement like that; it's just not something SQL can do. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve by combining them like that?

Comment: The SQL table structure as described, has a few _code smells_; duplicate and unclear column names, hence non-intuitive query solutions. The `company/user/role model` is the most commonly used relation (in multi-user applications); many good examples can be found.

The root of the problems stem from violations of _SQL normal forms_. Skipping details, the _users table_ should have columns: id, name, role. The user_company table is a _join table_ and should have columns (that are foreign keys): user_id, company_id. Now, a single query suffices. For multiple roles, add a user_role join table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two separate update statement as below:

To update company:

```
UPDATE company SET company.p_name = 'Javeria Rauf' WHERE company.p_id = 9 ;
```

To update users:

```
UPDATE users SET users.p_name = 'Javeria Rauf', users.role_def='Admin' WHERE users.p_id = 9 ;
```